# Jenkins FATAL Error

Tags: jenkins, build, fatal-error

I have jenkins v 1.580 installed on windows.

All my jobs were working fine until afternoon but all of a sudden all the jobs started failing with the following error,(The only error)

**FATAL: (class: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream, method:  signature: (Ljava/io/OutputStream;ZI[B)V) Incompatible argument to function
FATAL: (class: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream, method:  signature: (Ljava/io/OutputStream;ZI[B)V) Incompatible argument to function
Finished: null**

The only thing i found to happen in the afternoon was a windows security update but that also I was able to get uninstalled with the help of IT.

(I have close to 50 jobs running. Is there any limitation on number of jobs)
Can anyone tell me what could be wrong here?

Following the error snippet I can see from jenkins.error,

a user in error attempting to specify a java: URL name in a non-J2EE client or server environment. Throwing

Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0

(position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1)

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 (position:

START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1)

Should I go for reinstallation of jenkins?

Thanks in advance.

Sakthivel C

Answer (score 1):

Are you using fingerprint plugin? It appears as if fingerprint files were corrupted.

Delete the directory "fingerprints" from JENKINS_HOME and restart your Jenkins to resolve the issue.

If that doesn't work, paste the exact error log here.

Comment: I tried deleting the fingerprint folder but to see the same issue.How to paste the error log here? I m unable to attach the file as well.

Comment: Also another weired thing is that the nightly build(i.e the scheduled build) is working fine but when I click on the BuildNow it throws the fatal error.